# How to update values in an array with values from another array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays:

```
[{ Name: ‘Bart’,  col2: +4,  col3:4},
  { Name: ‘Marge’, col2: +8,  col3:},
  { Name: ‘Bart’,  col2: -3 , col3:8},
  { Name: ‘Homer’, col2: +12, col3:4},
  { Name: ‘Bart’,  col2: +12, col3:2},
  { Name: ‘Homer’, col2: +2,  col3:13}]
```

and

```
[{ Name: ‘Bart’,  col2:4},
 { Name: ‘Marge’, col2:12},
 { Name: ‘Bart’,  col2:4},
 { Name: ‘Bart’,  col2:4},
 { Name: ‘Homer’,  col2:4}]
```

I want the update the contents from col3 in array1 with the contents from col2 in array2. Col2 in array2 contains multiple times the correct values (the same ones for each name) and I want to update col3 in array1 with these values.

I know how to do this in Python but I'm completely lost in javascript.

*** edit

I tried this:

```
array1.forEach((x) => {
        const bla = array2.find((y) => y.Name === x.Name);
        x.col3 = bla.col2;  
        });
```

and it is in the last part that I got stuck ... How to update (replace) the value with another one.

I know, data is a bit weird, I'm trying to make one array (or object) of 3 different ones. And yes, the values in array2/col2 are the same for 'Bart', 'Marge',... but in array1 they are a bit random.

Comment: I'd suspect most Python solutions would be more or less directly translatable to JS. What specific issue are you having? How do you want to deal with the `Name` collisions? E.g., the first `Bart` in array 1--what value should `col3` get from array 2? The first? Last? What differentiates the different `Bart`s? Should all `Bart`s in array one be updated with the **same** value from array 2, and which value in array 2 (although in the example all `Bart` values are the same, so...)

Comment: Are you looking to loop over one of the arrays and, within that loop, find information in the other array to update?  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Without knowing the actual requirements it's not really possible to provide a solution, but it's not clear what hasn't worked w/ your JS solution(s).

Comment: The Dave Brigade uses a lot of words :rofl:

Comment: It seems you have Objects, not arrays, although Objects are very similar to arrays.

Why are there repeated names in the Objects?

W3schools has some good info
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Please add expected output for better understanding.

Comment: ```array1 = array1.map(e => {
   const bla = array2.find((y) => y.Name === x.Name);
   return { ...e, col3: bla.col2 };
})```

Something like this should do the job

Comment: maybe it should be: `x.col3 = y.col2;  ` ?

Comment: Thx @NicolasMenettrier, this helped me a lot. I tried almost the same, but it failed and now I see what I did wrong: ...e
thx a lot!!!!!